# ruby, regex extract price from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In ruby i have a string like this:

```
str= 43,69 €
```

Is possible with a regex obtain `43,69` ?

I have tried with:

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/
```

but the output is incorrect: `43.0`

Comment: The variant that you were using would work if the decimal separator was a `dot`.

Comment: I think you've got your answer, but for other regex situations I use: http://rubular.com/ to test them. It's very useful.

Comment: I find it quite surprising you get an output of `43.0` with an input of `43,69` :)

Comment: I think question needs to be edit with posted values 43.0 instead 43,69...

Comment: `/\d+(?:,\d+)?/` works for `43,69` but if i have `43,00 €` the output is `43,0` so is not correct.

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?/
```

The `[.,]` part matches decimal separator for a dot or a comma. If you are sure thet decimal separator will be a comma, you can use this:

```
/\d+(?:,\d+)?/
```

Comment: In a character class (`[...]`), you don't have to escape the dot `.`, it will always match the actual dot. As you can see, `"," =~ /[.]/` is `nil` (since it only matches the actual dot). And the pipe character `|` will also match a pipe character (`"|" =~ /[|]/` yields `0` (i.e, match at position 0)), it does not act like an OR inside a character class. A character class already is acting like an OR (any of the characters inside). Thus, just do `[.,]` instead of `[\.|,]`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for this precision. I updated my answer accordingly